# 'extraHeaders' doesn't work for onResponseStarted

Tags: google-chrome-extension

'ResponseHeaders' is OK. I can get response headers in details. But 'extraHeaders' doesn't work. The response headers is undefined. I want to get 'Set-Cookie' so I have to set extraHeaders.

```
chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
  function (details) {
    ws.send(details.url);
    console.log(details);
  }, {
  urls: ["<all_urls>"]
  },
  ['extraHeaders']
);
```

Comment: extraHeaders is an additional flag, but you still need to specify `'responseHeaders'`.

Comment: No. I tried specifying both 'responseHeaders' and 'extraHeaders'. It complains that only one of them can be specified at one time.

Comment: Doesn't complain here so I guess it's either a bug in Chrome or you did something weird.

Comment: I tried again. It worked! I didn't know why it wasn't working. Thanks. @wOxxOm